# Drupal 7, how to debug PDO errors

Tags: pdo, drupal-7

I have an error in a SQL request coming from a module of Drupal commerce,

```
PDOException : SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect 
integer value: '' for column 'commerce_discounts_target_id' at row 1: INSERT 
INTO {field_data_commerce_discounts} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, 
bundle, delta, language, commerce_discounts_target_id)
```

I can't find from where the insert is made, is there any way to have something like in symfony with the list of the methods used before the error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure xdebug to use breakpoints where you know the drupal is going to pass, for example if there is a form, you know that drupal is always going to pass for the hook_form_alter(). That' will show you the variables and methods used at this moment.

Anyway, for the sql exception is looks like the error comes from this function:

```
function commerce_discount_commerce_discount_insert($entity) {
```